# Post Request in Python with a cookie set, but still not sending the datas correctly

Tags: python, cookies, http-post

I am new to Python, but I guess I'm handling the problem not too bad after 3h of research.
My POST request is bypassing the login wall thanks to the cookie but it never posts the informations I'd like on the page. :(

Here's my code :

```
import requests

url = "url"
headers = {
'Cookie': 'cookie',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml',
'Accept-Language': 'en-gb,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
'Keep-Alive': '300',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '41'
}

payload = {
'seo_page[keyword]': 'test',
'commit': 'Save'
}

p = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print p.text.encode('utf8')
print p.encoding
print p.headers
```

Which is, I think, exactly what's advised in the 15 topics I've read about how to POST datas on webform page.

print p.text.encode('utf8') gives me the HTML without the datas I'm trying to send.

Any idea? :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good! The POST request was set properly but it was still not accepting the datas because of an edge case :
The website where I tried to POST is developped on Ruby on Rails and it asked for an additionnal authentification token (developped in order to avoid CSRF attacks).

Cheers !